# 'tf.app.flag' error in windows 10 64 bit , using python 6.4

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uname\Downloads\object-detection\generate_tfrecords.py", line 99, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "C:\Users\uname\Downloads\object-detection\generate_tfrecords.py", line 85, in main
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
  File "C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\tf_record.py", line 106, in __init__
    compat.as_bytes(path), compat.as_bytes(compression_type), status)
  File "C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:  : The system cannot find the path specified.

; No such process
```

Comment: Please give me a suggestion for this. I m trying  to train my own model for object detection

Comment: How about putting a little effort into your question? You get as much as you give.

Comment: what else you want to know @pinegulf

Comment: You'll need to put more info as to what you tried, your environment perhaps, etc.

Comment: basically , I'm trying to train my model through youtube tutorials of sentdex object detection module. i want to generate "train.record" and "test.record" files from  train. xml and test.xml files.But getting above error on my system because of tf.ap.flag()